# Mobx how to wait till Promise<axiosResponse> is done then run a different function

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have a Mobx Promise that I need to be finished first 100 % then run another function. when I have the function after the .then ... it runs first before the promise is done. but I need all the actions in promise is done first then run the next function

basically i need to know how I can make this sequential

Mobx

```
    a function(){   
        promise<axiosResponse>().then(resp =>{ 
                console.log('1') 
                do this();  
                and this();
         })

             now do this function();
              console.log('2')  
     }
```

the results is in this order..

2
1

but I want 1 to be done first 
and then start to do 2

Comment: It is hard to understand your question. Just input your code to inside then(), it will be done in sequence.

Comment: @bkm412 yah I am doing that now, but I just didnt wanted to be inside the .then() I thought maybe there is a way to detect that once everthing is done in .then() , we can run something else